# How The Process Context Can Be Leveraged In Modular Monolith

Tags: design, architecture, microservices

I'm currently on the research if my current monolith architecture
can be improved by moving to micro-services.

From what I saw, there are a lot of good things about micro-services
but there is a low of caveats and pit-falls that might complex
the whole system (transactions, data-query, data-sync and duplication, fault tolerance, error handling, etc)

Seems that there is the middle ground of going into a "Modular Monolith" ([1](http://www.kamilgrzybek.com/design/modular-monolith-primer/),[2](https://medium.com/design-and-tech-co/modular-monoliths-a-gateway-to-microservices-946f2cbdf382#:~:text=By%20this%20definition%2C%20monolithic%20is,easier%20maintenance%20down%20the%20line.),[3](https://towardsdatascience.com/looking-beyond-the-hype-is-modular-monolithic-software-architecture-really-dead-e386191610f8)) where the system is designed vertically into a loosely coupled modules that interact using APIs.

The question is how the fact that these modules operate against the same database and sit in the same process space can be leveraged to ease the complexity, i.e:

1. Can the modules declare "Transaction Context" in their API that will allow an ACID transaction when there is a cross-modules business logic operation? (in contrary to micro-service where it's not achievable by design)
   For example:

   ```
   transaction_context = DB.generate_transcation_ctx()
   moduleA.do_operationA(transaction_context, arg1, arg2, ...)
   moduleB.do_operationB(transaction_context, arg1, arg2, ...)
   transaction_context.commit()
   ```

   So a cross-module buisness operation can be committed/rollbacked at once - 
    instead of using 2PC, SAGA and other techniques from the micro-services world.
2. Declaring database Views in special modules that will allow joining data on the database level and not on the application level.

Are these will be a best practice? if not - how to leverage the fact that they are in the same process?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Transaction Context"? Secondly, please modify the item marked 2 to be in the form of a question. Lastly, in terms of your final sentence, please provide some context as to how you want to compare monolith and microservices so that your question can be better answered.

Comment: Thanks, made some edits. 
Do you have some insights about my questions?

Comment: 2. above is still not a stand question so is likely to create some confusion. That said, I have added a partial answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting into microservices without refactoring your database is not really taking full advantage of microservices.

Firstly, you have a lesser opportunity to scale because your microservices are all hitting the same database. If you change your table design to separate concerns, you can find opportunities to scale different parts differently and to move data into different databases that are more tightly linked to the specific applications and their usage needs.

Secondly, adding the microservices only at an application level means more running processes to look after and more asynchronous operations which adds complexity. You are also potentially adding more communication between the processes to achieve your service design.

Lastly, because your database still has a tighter coupling between different views of the data, you lose out on the flexibility that could come with fully decoupled microservice designs. You will often find that you need to change several microservices implementations at a time because both are tied to some of the same underlying data. That happens less when the microservices are more effectively decoupled.